# How to teach my cat not to bring toys to my bed?

Tags: cats, training, play, toys

My cat sleeps on my bed by my side. Even if I make separate bed and put her there she would not listen and come to sleep by my side. Anyway I kind of like it and has no problems.

But the problem lies elsewhere. My cat has mouse toys. Moreover, she sees every small movable objects throughout the house as her toys. And such things keep mounting on my bed. After I clean my bed, again she brings them.

Now, is there any way to teach her not to bring her toys to my bed, without forcing her out of the bed?

Comment: Simply through the toys off your bed without throwing the cat. Problem solved. She may want you to play with her so do so, with the toys she's getting you.

Comment: @toothless199 that is what I asked, regularly I have to clean my bed, with all the junks in it. Imagine after all day work, you are going to bed only to find, pepsi cap, water ottle cap, clips, pen cap, paper scraps, etc. on your bed.

Comment: My cat would even bring the dead mouse to the bed. So proud! I think she is trying to show you everything that she owns and share it with you. This is hard for me too because she wakes me up. The only thing I can do is lock the door, and she cries.

Comment: Lol funny, so you're just gonna have to teach her to stop by catching her in the act and telling her ''No''. You know how that works? but the problem is that the cat is only trying to play with you or be nice and show you her prey toys. So it may not be nice to stop her afterall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decrease this behavior you can limit her access to small movable objects. Put toys away after play time, and pick up small non-toy items and put those away too. This will not train her not to do it, it will simply prevent her from practicing the behavior.

This type of caching behavior in carnivores is instinctive and serves to fulfill the primary motivation of feeding. As such is not a good candidate for training ‘not to do’. Instincts that satisfy primary motivators (feeding, fighting and, procreation) are subject to ‘instinctive drift’. In other words the training doesn’t stick, and the behavior always returns. It is better to prevent her from engaging in the behavior by taking the toys away.

I’ve had cats bringing me toys in bed or on the couch when they want to play. Try throwing the things she brings. If you can get her to chase things she brings to you, you can shape this behavior into a game of fetch, thus redirecting her unwanted behavior into something more acceptable.

Read more about instinctive drift here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instinctive_drift?wprov=sfti1

http://psychclassics.yorku.ca/Breland/misbehavior.htm